# Group search not available on all search screens except for search builder

Tags: groups, permissions, search, multisite

Ever since Civi 5.35.2, group search does not populate for non-admin users. See discussion here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19372. Before all groups would show. On multisite. Users have `CiviCRM Multisite: list all groups in domain permission.` Groups do show in search builder.

What is curious is a near identical staging environment it does work. It is same Civi version and pretty near close to what is on production. I've ruled out extensions (renamed directory) and many WP plugins. Can someone assist in narrowing down where the problem is?

Find Contacts:

[image]

Advanced Search:

[image]

Find Contributions (group dropdown entirely missing)
[image]

Same behavior occurs in Find Participants and Find Memberships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this commit: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19372/commits/7ffbc14effcf98ade1381002375947b36af712b6 got the groups to show again.

For me, listing all groups to all users is fine and preferable over group search missing entirely. This is what WP users were used to for some time. My understanding is that this was Drupal based functionality. Users can only see the contacts they are permissioned to in whatever group it is as well.

Using multisite on 5.35.2

Answer (score 1):

If you open your web browser's Developer Tools (press F12) and go to the Network tab, you should be able to get more information.  When you click the "Groups" drop-down, look for the new request at the bottom of the Network tab.  It will almost certainly have a purple "500" or "403" instead of the green "200" next to it.  Click that line, check the "Response" sub-tab, and you'll have a detailed error message.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not showing the request.

Comment: That means that either a) you're filtering out XHR requests (check the subtabs of the Network tab) or b) you have a JavaScript error on the page - which would actually explain this problem pretty well.  Check the "Console" tab for red errors - most (but not all) mean that your JavaScript has an error, and the browser is refusing to process further JavaScript.

Comment: Nothing under XHR requests and no JS errors :( It looks like a permissions issue to me, especially on the screenshots where the group field doesn't show at all, but can't figure out what permission may be missing.

Comment: I've isolated it down to that group search works for the same permission set on domain ID 1 but not child sites.

Comment: Since I replicated on another multisite I've logged an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2827